# 'insert into' in 'execute immediate' clause

Tags: sql, plsql, insert, execute-immediate

Can you check this and tell me why I've got an error, please? How should it look? I have no idea what's wrong here. I need to create a table in a function, and in the same function insert data into this table:

```
create or replace
function new_tab ( pyt IN varchar2) return number
IS
a number;
b varchar2(20);
begin
a:= ROUND(dbms_random.value(1, 3));
b:='example';

-- This works perfect
execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE create_tmp_table'|| a  ||'(i VARCHAR2(50))';

-- Here`s the problem
execute immediate 'insert into create_tmp_table'||a|| 'values ('|| b ||')'; 

exception
when others then
dbms_output.put_line('ERROR-'||SQLERRM);

return 0;
end;
```

My result is:
`ERROR-ORA-00926: missing VALUES keyword. Process exited.`

Where is the mistake?

Comment: An INSERT statement has been entered without the keyword VALUES or SELECT. Either a VALUES clause or a SELECT subquery must follow the INSERT INTO clause.

Comment: I see the word values right after ||a||.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are creating a dynamic insert command you have to create it as is. So you are missing the single quotes for the value that is varchar:

```
execute immediate 
     'insert into create_tmp_table'||a|| ' values ('''|| b ||''');'; 
                                                    ^here     ^and here
```

And a good suggestion for this type of error is to do some debug. On your case you could create a varchar2 variable and put your insert on it then you use the `dbms_output.put_line` to this variable. Then you will have your sql command that you can test direct on your database. Something like:

```
declare
   sqlCommand varchar2(1000);
   --define a and b
begin
   --put some values in a and b
   sqlCommand := 'insert into create_tmp_table'||a|| ' values ('''|| b ||''');';
   dbms_output.put_line(sqlCommand);
end;
```

Then you will know what is wrong with the dynamic command.

Answer (score 0):

`execute immediate 'insert into TABLE'||a||' (COLUMN_NAME) values (:val)' using b;`

This way you don't have to bother with escaping your values (SQL-injection hack) and correctly casting the type.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm